# Swift: How to drag image view to "snap" up against edge of the next image view

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

Using Swift 4 in XCode, I have several image views on the screen.  I have added a gesture recognizer to one, and am able to move that image around the screen with a pan action.
What I'd like is that when I move that image NEXT to another image view on the screen, it "snaps" into place right next to it.  (imagine magnetic lego blocks - and when one gets close to the next one, it snaps and attaches) -- as opposed to, say, being able to drag the movable image on TOP of the static image.

Can anyone guide me toward an answer, as I don't know what this concept is called. 
 (I'm not really trying to use animation, as it should only move based on a user's swipe.)  Any tutorial links would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: At the end of the user's move, you would need to work out the closest image to lock beside, and then change it's co-ordinates via code to do the snapping. You would do this in a UIView.animate(withDuration). i.e. the first part of the move is as a result of the user's swipe, but then your code takes over to position the image.

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I did and it worked great!

Comment: did got it, Emma. Would like to share the result? thx